# threshold rule for two penalty terms

Tags: optimization, threshold, regularization, fused-lasso

Can any one recommend some reference or advice for getting a (hard) thresholding rule combining $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ for solving an optimization problem with the two penalty (regularization) terms? Maybe fused Lasso is an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your question is: how to determine the values of weight penalties?

Comment: @Hossein Hmmm I should say yes

Answer (score 0):

Just as two hints:

- Empirically evaluate different weight penalties using cross-validation. That is, divide your data into the training and validation sets and try different weight penalties to train the model on the training set and choose those values that have the best performance on the validation set.
- Use the method proposed by David MacKay to empirically obtain the values for weight penalties without cross-validation. Take a look at [this coursera course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfG1nyaWd4A&list=PLnnr1O8OWc6Zjy8KDuRu5X7AmFslVBxYA&index=6) for more detail:
  Geoffrey Hinton. "Lecture 9.6- MacKays Quick and Dirty Method of Setting Weight Costs." COURSERA: Neural networks for machine learning (2012).